# How to rebuild node.js addon when source changes

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, nodemon

I have a node.js app and I have created a native addon.  (In case you need background info, native addons for node.js can be created [like this](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)).

In my development environment I want it to watch source files (these are C++ source files, in this case) and automatically rebuild my addon when the C++ source files change, and also automatically restart the node application after the build completes.

I'm certain there's more than one way to accomplish this, but I went down the road of trying nodemon.  But I couldn't figure out how to get nodemon to wait for the build to finish before restarting the application.

I figure npm can probably do this itself too with a script, perhaps with some kind of a watch package.  So I'm open to alternative approaches if there's something easier.

So when any of my source files change, really all I need is for `node-gyp build` to run at the right point in the restart workflow (stop node, recompile, restart node). Right now it rebuilds the addon and restarts the application **without waiting for the build to complete**, and that's undesirable.

Here's my nodemon.json file:

```
{
  "watch": [
    "addon/"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "addon/build/"
  ],
  "events": {
    "restart": "cd addon && node-gyp build"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,cc,h"
}
```

This doesn't work because the "restart" is like an event, in that my script that runs node-gyp fires and executes, but it doesn't block restarting until the build is finished.

I was hoping it would work more like middleware, where it would run the build script after the app is terminated, but before it restarts the app.  I also consulted [this relevant nodemon issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/310), but there's no concrete suggestion there about how to make that happen.

I need to change something so that the rebuild (node-gyp step) will happen automatically when the source changes and then restart nicely.

*Note: Later I'll restructure it so that it only rebuilds the addon when the relevant C++ source files change, and just restarts the app when .js files change without rebuilding the C++ addon, but first I need to figure out getting the node-gyp build step to happen at the right time.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this by having **nodemon** use the `-x` option to run **npm**.  Then the npm script can execute the *build* and *run* scripts sequentially.

Here's the relevant part of my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon -x \"npm run buildrun\"",
  "buildrun": "npm run build && npm run server",
  "build": "echo Building Addon && cd addon && node-gyp build",
  "server": "nodemon server.js",
}
```

You kickstart this by running `npm run dev`.

`dev` runs nodemon with the `-x` option and the command is `npm run buildrun`.  Then nodemon restarts the npm `buildrun` script every time code changes.  This was the main part I had trouble figuring out.

To explain the rest, the `buildrun` script runs two scripts back to back.  The first one (`build`) builds the addon and the second one (`server`) runs the server.

The server script actually runs nodemon as well: it runs another nodemon to run the server script with `nodemon server.js`.

> *Technically, by having npm calling nodemon again (with the right configuration files, different arguments and context) nodemon could
>   watch a different piece of the codebase and restart a different part
>   of the system (e.g., watch just the server code without rebuilding the
>   whole addon, which is what my actual code does.)*

By calling nodemon with the `-x` option and having the entire build-and-run script get restarted when code changes, I was able to sequence the actions to get nodemon to first build the addon, wait for the build to complete, and then run the server.

This `nodemon -x \"npm ...\"` technique wasn't obvious to me at first and it actually took me half a year to come up with this solution.  So, I'm sharing this because other people may find this technique useful.