# Is it possible to configure concurrently to run a task sequentially?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, concurrently

My NPM package has the following scripts to

1. Start MongoDB.
2. Build an angular app and having it watched with any changes.
3. Start an express server using nodemon.

   ```
   "scripts": {
   "start_db": "mongod",
   "start_client": "ng build --output-path ./server/public/ --watch",
   "start_server": "nodemon --inspect -w server ./server/server.js",
   "start_all": "concurrently \"mongod\" \"nodemon --inspect -w server ./server/server.js\" \"ng build --output-path ./server/public/ --watch\""}
   ```

I want to do them all using a single command, so I add a script "start_all" and use **concurrently**.

However, when the express server starts, mongodb is not yet started and errors report.

> [1] 2019-07-15 13:36:54 - error - Connection to DB failed.
>   MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on
>   first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:27017] [1]     at Pool. (/repository/dashboard-js/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
>   [1]     at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13) [1]     at connect
>   (/repository/dashboard-js/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
>   [1]     at makeConnection
>   (/repository/dashboard-js/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:39:11)
>   [1]     at callback
>   (/repository/dashboard-js/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:261:5)
>   [1]     at Socket.err
>   (/repository/dashboard-js/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:286:7)
>   [1]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20) [1]     at
>   Socket.emit (events.js:198:13) [1]     at emitErrorNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8) [1]     at emitErrorAndCloseNT
>   (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3) [1]     at process._tickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) [1] [nodemon] app crashed -
>   waiting for file changes before starting...

Are there any way to fix this issue? For example, can I configure concurrently so that it only executes "start_client" and "start_server" after "start_db" completes?

Comment: (1) Why are using "concurrently" if you need to start things sequentially? (2) Even if you start sequentially, there is a delay between mongo reporting a successful start and it being ready to accept requests. I'd look at something like `wait_for` to wait for mongo be actually available before doing the next action.

Comment: I once asked and answered a question very similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605477/1563833.  Basically making use of `&&` to run scripts sequentially might be the only hint you need from that answer.